# Devemos desintegrar a tag [integração]?

Tags: debate, tag-específica

Fiz uma análise e minha percepção inicial é que o uso da [integração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integra%c3%a7%c3%a3o) é quase sempre circunstancial. Em muitos casos não acrescenta nada. Mas talvez tenha alguma utilidade. De fato as perguntas são sobre o assunto, ainda que cada uma com um significado diferente, o que dá a pensar. Não consegui formar uma opinião se é uma boa *tag* ou não.

Você consegue fazer uma avaliação nas perguntas e dizer aqui o que acha?

Comment: a tag bem que ajuda na formação do contexto, quase sempre está associada com a tag mysql, oracle, ou seja, ligada ao banco de dados. Então querem dizer que precisam integrar app ao db. Podemos entender que isso está explícito?

Comment: @durtto na verdade só 3 perguntas estão juntas com *tags* de banco de dados. Em geral o uso é bem genérico.

Comment: Vi as perguntas e concordo com a sua análise, daí ficar também dúvidas, talvez por a tag não ter descrição. Sem uma descrição é difícil de tomar uma decisão. Se não encontrar-mos uma que torne a tag útil, talvez seja melhor "desintegrar"

Comment: @ramaral se ela se manter viva, criar uma descrição é um passo. Só não sei se isso evitaria muito o uso para qualquer coisa que minimamente tenha alguma **integração qualquer**.

Comment: Concordo, ela é muito abrangente.

Comment: Realmente, muito genérica.